# How can I flip the result of WebGLRenderingContext.readPixels()?

Tags: canvas, webgl

Why is the imageData that I get from `WebGLRenderingContext.readPixels()` upside down?

I try to do the folowing:

```
var gl = renderer.domElement.getContext("webgl")

var pixels = new Uint8Array(gl.drawingBufferWidth * gl.drawingBufferHeight * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

var imageData = new ImageData(Uint8ClampedArray.from(pixels), gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

but the result is an image that is mirrored along the x-axis (i.e.: flipped upside down).

I've also tried to use scale after `ctx.putImageData` like this:

```
ctx.scale(1, -1);
```

But no results. Reversing the pixels also doesn't work.

By now I understand that putImageData() uses coordinates that start from top left, and readPixels() starts from bottom left.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to flip the image or avoid the problem altogether?

Comment: @defghi1977 thanks to everyone for the very diverse answers - this is not my day job, so I'll only be able to test them in about 12 hours - I'll accept one then. From reading them I wish I could accept them all

Comment: @Kaiido thanks to everyone for the very diverse answers - this is not my day job, so I'll only be able to test them in about 12 hours - I'll accept one then. From reading them I wish I could accept them all

Comment: @gman thanks to everyone for the very diverse answers - this is not my day job, so I'll only be able to test them in about 12 hours - I'll accept one then. From reading them I wish I could accept them all

Comment: I ended up using drawImage - quite straightforward! Thanks to all

Comment: In my case gl.readPixels() was returning the data upside-down because of a previous call to gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true); - so preventing it when wanting to retrieve pixels solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're going to copy to a 2d canvas to flip you might as well skip the `readPixels`. Just use `drawImage`

```
var dstX = 0;
var dstY = 0;
var dstWidth = ctx.canvas.width;
var dstHeight = ctx.canvas.height;    
ctx.drawImage(gl.canvas, dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight);
```

The browser will do the right thing and the result will be right side up.

Example:

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("#webgl").getContext("webgl");
var ctx = document.querySelector("#two_d").getContext("2d");

// fill webgl canvas with red on top and blue on bottom
gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
for (var y = 0; y < 15; ++y) {
  var v = y / 14;
  gl.scissor(0, y * 10, 300, 10);
  gl.clearColor(v, 0, 1 - v, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

// copy it to 2d canvas
var dstX = 0;
var dstY = 0;
var dstWidth = ctx.canvas.width;
var dstHeight = ctx.canvas.height;
ctx.drawImage(gl.canvas, dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight);
```

```css
canvas { 
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="webgl"></canvas>
<canvas id="two_d"></canvas>
```

If you really did want to call `gl.readPixels` for some reason (you had no intent of every putting them in a 2d canvas, then you can just flip the bytes

```
var width = gl.drawingBufferWidth;
var height = gl.drawingBufferHeight
var pixels = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

var halfHeight = height / 2 | 0;  // the | 0 keeps the result an int
var bytesPerRow = width * 4;

// make a temp buffer to hold one row
var temp = new Uint8Array(width * 4);
for (var y = 0; y < halfHeight; ++y) {
  var topOffset = y * bytesPerRow;
  var bottomOffset = (height - y - 1) * bytesPerRow;

  // make copy of a row on the top half
  temp.set(pixels.subarray(topOffset, topOffset + bytesPerRow));

  // copy a row from the bottom half to the top
  pixels.copyWithin(topOffset, bottomOffset, bottomOffset + bytesPerRow);

  // copy the copy of the top half row to the bottom half 
  pixels.set(temp, bottomOffset);
}
```

Example:

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("#webgl").getContext("webgl");
var ctx = document.querySelector("#two_d").getContext("2d");

// fill webgl canvas with red on top and blue on bottom
gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
for (var y = 0; y < 15; ++y) {
  var v = y / 14;
  gl.scissor(0, y * 10, 300, 10);
  gl.clearColor(v, 0, 1 - v, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}


var width = gl.drawingBufferWidth;
var height = gl.drawingBufferHeight
var pixels = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

var halfHeight = height / 2 | 0;  // the | 0 keeps the result an int
var bytesPerRow = width * 4;

// make a temp buffer to hold one row
var temp = new Uint8Array(width * 4);
for (var y = 0; y < halfHeight; ++y) {
  var topOffset = y * bytesPerRow;
  var bottomOffset = (height - y - 1) * bytesPerRow;

  // make copy of a row on the top half
  temp.set(pixels.subarray(topOffset, topOffset + bytesPerRow));

  // copy a row from the bottom half to the top
  pixels.copyWithin(topOffset, bottomOffset, bottomOffset + bytesPerRow);

  // copy the copy of the top half row to the bottom half 
  pixels.set(temp, bottomOffset);
}

// This part is not part of the answer. It's only here
// to show the code above worked
// copy the pixels in a 2d canvas to show it worked
var imgdata = new ImageData(with, height);
imgdata.data.set(pixels);
ctx.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);
```

```css
canvas { 
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="webgl"></canvas>
<canvas id="two_d"></canvas>
```

Comment: hehe, silly me I didn't though of direct drawImage from webgl to 2Dctx... But `ctx.drawImage(img, x, height, width, -height)` does not work, what you do is just like `drawImage(0,-1)` (why -1 btw ?) ; you need `ctx.scale(1, -1)` if you want to actually flip it, but I'm not sure OP even needs this if the problem is from `readPixels` (you'll know this better than me). Also, I think that flipping the dataArray is slower than the drawImage version I provided (where everything is made on GPU). Anyway +1 for the first approach.

Comment: Where does it not work ? I have a working example in my answer ?

Comment: which is not flipped... As I said, what you did is the same as `drawImage(img, 0,-1)`. I still don't get why the `-1` and I guess that what you wanted to do with all this `y :height, height: -height` was to flip the image vertically, but it doesn't work this way. So your first code block should only be `ctx.drawImage(gl.canvas,0,0)` and in your snippet you can also remove all these wrong and useless `dstX, dstY etc.`

Comment: I see your point, in which case I updated my answer. If you're drawing to a 2d canvas there's nothing to do. As for your answer using putImage etc that uses way more memory (4x?) and no it doesn't stay on the GPU.

Comment: uh? Why it wouldn't stay on the GPU ? (of course I was comparing your alternative which uses 2 Uint arrays + a lot of `set()`, not the direct `drawImage`.) After the putImageData (that I wrongly took as mandatory), everything is done on the GPU : drawImage + compositing and that's it.

Comment: oh and why are you using getImageData in this second snippet ? to create an imagedata, either use `new ImageData([Uint8ClampedArray,] w, h)` when supported or at a very least `ctx.createImageData(w,h)` but not getImageData... Your *4x* seems completely wrong to me.

Comment: First off the guy was using readPixels. So there's already a copy on CPU. You're then taking that copy, making a new canvas (2x), putting it in an imagedata (3x), then if he actually wants the flipped data he'd have to pull out another imagedata (4x). Anything related to imagedata is on the CPU. The only part of your example that's on the GPU is the actual flip but copying say ~4meg to and from the GPU is not fast. So for why getImageData I'll fix that but that piece of the code is only to verify the data was flipped, it's not relevant to the answer. ImageData didn't exist at one point.

Comment: But the only relevant part of my code is the `flip` method, which expects an imageData as input. All the remaining is just like your gl initialisation : I needed an ImageData to do the demo. So there isn't even an need for a second canvas, `#normal` is the original canvas and is not part of the function at all, just like your `#webgl` , and `#flipped` is the 2D output, which OP already has. So all in all, I just create **1** imageData, which can share the same buffer as the one from `readPixel`, and I only put it. Here is a fair perf-test and oh surprise ! https://jsperf.com/flip-imagedata/1

Comment: Expecting imagedata as input means someone has to make the imagedata since readPixels doesn't return one. And, actually you need 5x the memory. Canvas can't draw itself flipped to itself without making a copy. As for your test you left in the verification which is irrelevant to the code, you also didn't pull out the data of your canvas since the OP asked for data, not a canvas which means you left an entire transfer from GPU to CPU.

Comment: Looking into it further there are bugs in the browsers. [If you run this example in firefox](https://jsperf.com/flipping-for-fun-and-profit/1) it runs faster in mine but I had to work around browser bugs to get the speed up (use one giant copy and only call `copyWithin`). Looking into why those bugs exist

Comment: ??? Why do you create a new output canvas in the loop ? In my solution, all is done on the output 2dCanvas, I only create an ImageData from the readPixel arrayBuffer (so my imageData shares the same buffer as OP's one => memory impact === `'{width:int, height:int, data:pointer}'.length` and put it on the canvas, just like you have to do at the end of your solution. Otherwise it's just compositing and yes canvas can draw itself on itself without a copy since it always have a copy of itself in memory anyway, used for whatever drawing you do on it.

Comment: Also, your *JSPerf bug* is your typo : `createElement("cavnas")` has no method `getContext`...

Comment: Ok, so you're still only using 4x the memory. I had a bug in teardown, [so did jsperf](https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com/issues/332). Now that jsperf is fixed I can see my bug.  As for why I create a canvas in your code because you should not have keep a special second canvas around just for flipping but that's fine, [we can remove that](https://jsperf.com/flipping-for-fun-and-profit/1). No, canvas does not keep a second copy around. Why would it? The only time a second copy would be needed is to draw yourself into yourself. That's an extremely rare case.

Comment: I think you're missing the point about canvas needing a copy. Canvas is implemented as a texture using a framebuffer. You can't draw a texture that is a framebuffer into into the same texture. So having canvas texture around isn't enough. To draw yourself into yourself you need a 2nd texture containing a copy of yourself. This is no different than if you did it yourself using WebGL. You can't use a texture as a source that is the same as a texture you're currently rendering into.

Comment: But there is no "helper canvas" either, it's just the **output canvas**. Our codes can not share the same teardown, I do my operation directly **on the output canvas**. I start where you do stop, except that I did nothing in between. For the self-copy, I have to admit that I didn't gone into every UAs implementations to check, but as far as my dev tools can tell, there is no magical canvas copy appearing  in the memory when drawing a 2d canvas on itself.

Comment: There is no output canvas. The question is not "how do I flip a canvas" it's "how do I flip the result of readpixels"

Comment: But I clearly state in my answer *"since you seem to draw it on a 2DContext anyway"* so that's where I start and end. And funnily, that's also where your snippets both ends too. My answer shows that you can flip an ImageData on a 2dContext, without having to do the heavy CPU operations of copying and sorting the data.

Comment: And my answer shows your answer is pointless because if you just want the result in a canvas just call drawimage. No reason to call readPixels in the first place. If you are calling readpixel for reason then your answer is both slower, uses 4x the memory, and is lossy because putImageData will do alpha premultiply.

Comment: It's pointless if you've got access to the webgl context yes and that's what I said in my first comment, but if you've got the readPixel result from somewhere else, and need to put it as an ImageData on a 2dContext, then it's not that useless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134700/discussion-between-gman-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a webgl way to flip `readPixels`, and I suspect there is indeed a way to "avoid the problem altogether", but since you seem to draw it on a 2DContext anyway, here is a way to flip your `putImageData`.

Since `putImageData` is not affected by context's transforms, simply doing `ctx.scale(1,-1); ctx.putImageData()` won't work.

You'll need to putImageData, then flip its transforms, before drawing the canvas on itself.

Use `globalCompositeOperation = 'copy'` if you have transparency.

```js
function flip(imageData){
  var ctx = flipped.getContext('2d');
  flipped.width = imageData.width;
  flipped.height = imageData.height;
  // first put the imageData
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0,0);
  // because we've got transparency
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
  ctx.scale(1,-1); // Y flip
  ctx.translate(0, -imageData.height); // so we can draw at 0,0
  ctx.drawImage(flipped, 0,0);
  // now we can restore the context to defaults if needed
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  }

/* remaining is just for the demo */
var ctx = normal.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.onload = getImageData;
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png";

function getImageData(){
  normal.width = this.width;
  normal.height = this.height;
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
  imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,this.width, this.height);
  flip(imageData);
  }
```

```css
canvas{border: 1px solid}
body{background: ivory;}
```

```html
<canvas id="normal"></canvas>
<canvas id="flipped"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flip pixels of ImadaData directly like this.

```
const imageData = new ImageData(Uint8ClampedArray.from(pixels),gl.drawingBufferWidth,gl.drawingBufferHeight);

const w = imageData.width, h = imageData.height;
const data = imageData.data;
Array.from({length: h}, (val, i) => data.slice(i * w * 4, (i + 1) * w * 4))
        .forEach((val, i) => data.set(val, (h - i - 1) * w * 4));
```

Comment: This method sometimes fires a "RangeError Source image is too large"